# Automatically Submit Form If there is Value

Tags: javascript

I have a problem to store visitor session. But I have an idea to fix this by automatically submit the form input if there is value.

If I use the auto submit with javascript, it will do automatically submit regardless of whether or not an existing value in the input section.

HTML code

```
    <form id="id_form" action="login.php" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="this_value" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="this_password" /><br />
    Save password: <input type="checkbox" name="session"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {submitform();})
{
  document.getElementById("id_form").submit();
}
</script>
```

Visitors who save password checking section, will immediately submit automatically if a time to visit this page again.
How can this work, is there a solution?

Comment: Did you want to skip the login form if the user flags a *keep me logged* checkbox? In this case you should set up a cookies with relevant informations and use it.

Comment: @Eineki - I have a script for the login code, and after the browser is closed, then the session ends immediately. However, the result remains in the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following JavaScript code:

```
if (document.getElementById("user").value !== "" && 
    document.getElementById("password").value !== "") {
  document.getElementById("id_form").submit();
}
```

Place it at the end of your HTML document to make sure the HTML has already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onchange or onkeyup events
so in your input tag when user enters value form submits automatically

for example :

```
<input onkeyup="sendform(this.value)" type="text" />
<script>
function sendform(inputvalue)
{
// this is the value of input now you can submit your form
}
```